# Is ftruncate() always precise?

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory

I am trying to `ftruncate` a shared memory object to a specific length. For example, I want to set its length to 1 byte using the following snippet:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
    struct stat fd_stat;
    int fd;

    fd = shm_open("NAME", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    fstat(fd, &fd_stat);

    printf("Size before: %lld\n", fd_stat.st_size);

    ftruncate(fd, 1);
    fstat(fd, &fd_stat);

    printf("Size after: %lld\n", fd_stat.st_size);
}
```

Which in Ubuntu 20.04 prints:

```
Size before: 0
Size after: 1
```

That's the output I'd expect.

However, in macOS X Big Sur I get:

```
Size before: 0
Size after: 4096
```

As you see, it seems to be expanding the size to the size of a page.

The `ftruncate` [Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) reads:

> The truncate() and ftruncate() functions cause the regular file named by path or referenced by fd to be truncated to a **size of precisely *length* bytes**.

Nonetheless, the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nframe.html) is not as specific (*pun intended*):

> If fildes refers to a regular file, the ftruncate() function shall cause the size of the file to be **truncated to *length***. [...] If the file previously was smaller than this size, ftruncate() **shall increase the size of the file**.

Does that mean that `ftruncate` always sets the length to exactly the specified number of bytes? If indeed it does, it would entail that macOS X Big Sur is not *fully POSIX-compliant* (even though it is certified to be so). If not, how can I guarantee that it truncates `fd` to the size I want?

Comment: On the face of it, it looks like macOS behaivour is different. Have you checked whether the call fails and whether `errno` indicates anything?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that. It returns a success code (0). `errno` is left unchanged (0 as well).

Comment: How are you compiling your code?  `st_size` is of type `off_t`, which is not guaranteed to be 64 bits.  But `%lld` is the format specifier for a `long long int`, which is *at least* 64 bits.

Comment: A shared memory object is not a regular file.  The specifications talk about regular files.  For a shared memory object, one page (4 KiB) doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your question, @AndrewHenle. On macOS X, I'm compiling it with `gcc filename`. On Ubuntu, I have to link it (`gcc filename -lrt`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If that were to be the case, how can I guarantee the size to be exactly 1 byte?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need exactly 1 byte of shared memory?

Comment: I do not exactly need 1 byte. I can use other ways to solve my specific issue, which, as you say, is not fully related to my question. However, my intention on this question is mostly to know if this is due to a lack of compliance of macOS with the POSIX standard (and if there would be a way to make sure `ftruncate` behaves as expected in macOS). My main intention is to help other users who may come across this very same question in the future, not to solve my specific issue.

Comment: The ftruncate on SHM is actually optional in POSIX and even then [it only says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2013edition/functions/ftruncate.html): **"If the effect of ftruncate() is to decrease the size of a memory mapped file or a shared memory object and whole pages beyond the new end were previously mapped, then the whole pages beyond the new end shall be discarded.".** which is what you observed on macOS. So macOS isn't non-conforming to POSIX.

Comment: Your experimentation seems to demonstrate that you can't guarantee one byre for a shared memory object.  Either abandon your requirement for a single byte or don't use a shared memory object.  Those appear to be your choices.

Comment: The portion of the POSIX spec that you quoted starts with *"If fildes refers to a regular file"*. None of the rest of that quote is relevant to your question because shared memory is not a regular file.

Comment: I didn't even realize about that, @user3386109! That's a very good observation. I believe that's the best explanation possible :)

Comment: But the size is not being decreased, @P.P... It's actually being increased (a new page is mapped).

Comment: I guess @JonathanLeffler is right. Maybe there's no way to ensure this guarantee...

Comment: @AldánCreo Right. But POSIX doesn't mandate the same requirement for SHM as it does for regular files. So there's no conforming issue. But I don't know if there's a way to ensure the exact length that you're after.

Comment: Other than a different return value from `fstat`, what practical difference are you expecting to observe between a shared memory object of length 1, and one of length 4096?  The underlying hardware mechanisms mean that mapping, permissions, sharing, can only be controlled with page granularity anyway.  I think that's why you're getting all the XY problem comments - you seem very concerned about a difference which to others seems to be meaningless.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I believe, nevertheless, that this is a nonconformity with the POSIX specification, as the spec says (and I quote from below) that *"If fildes refers to a shared memory object, ftruncate() shall set the size of the shared memory object to length"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you cannot get a guarantee that your **shared memory object** will be of precisely the size you ask `ftruncate` to be. That's because, as @user3386109 said, *"The portion of the POSIX spec that you quoted starts with "**If fildes refers to a regular file**""*.

If you want to constrain yourself to an arbitrary length, you can always use an auxiliary variable to keep track of the size you assume it to be (even if the actual size might actually differ, which may not be that important after all). Your code would look like:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
    struct stat fd_stat;
    int fd;
    off_t fd_size;

    fd = shm_open("NAME", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    fstat(fd, &fd_stat);

    printf("Size before: %lld\n", fd_stat.st_size);

    fd_size = 1;

    ftruncate(fd, fd_size);
    fstat(fd, &fd_stat);

    printf("Actual size: %lld\n", fd_stat.st_size);
    printf("Perceived size: %lld\n", fd_size);
}
```

On top of that, if you want to share the size among different processes, you can turn `fd_size` into a `mmap`ed shared memory object to keep track of the size you assume it to be across them all.

Comment: The POSIX spec also says: "If fildes refers to a shared memory object, ftruncate() shall set the size of the shared memory object to length."

Comment: Can you post a link to that section?

Comment: It's on the same page, https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftruncate.html

Comment: You're right! I hadn't read that... So I guess this is a nonconformity with the POSIX spec on macOS, after all...